# SEO what Meta enables the left display of information in google?

Tags: google, google-search, meta-tags, meta-description

I have seen that when we make some search in google there is a left display of information sometimes in a box in Google. Please what Meta enables the left display of information on google like in the picture below  ?
[image]

Comment: I assume you mean the "right" display, not the left...if so please edit your question to get a meaningful answer

Comment: @Steve It all depends on how you look at it... for example... standing on your head. ;-)

Comment: @closetnoc I don't even need to do that, I am in Australia :o)

Comment: @Steve I think the OP is in New Zealand! BTW- Do toilets still work on the equator? Does any one know? Cheers Mate!!

Answer (score 2):

That information isn't being generated by on-page meta tags.That information is coming from Google My Business. You can add your business at:

[business.google.com](http://business.google.com)

Log in to GMB to edit all the information listed including:

- Name
- Address
- Phone number
- Website
- Open hours
- Photos
- and more

And best of all, it's FREE!

Comment: Google My Business is just one of many sources including Wikipedia, primary source business listing sites, etc. This is knowledge graph stuff. Case in point, a friend of mine has a construction company that has a card within the knowledge graph WITHOUT a website or Google My Business.